# formtype with ManyToOne cause other field error(null)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.6

i'm trying to create the following structure, but get 1 error that drive me crazy.

a client has many invoice,an invoice belongs to a client

i use the symfony2 formtype, doctrine orm entity,

CRUD work fine without the OneToMany in invoice entity, but after added the OneToMany relationship, then Create and Update always throw null error

the db structure:

```
client - id, username, email, [.....]

invoice - id, client_id, total, [.....]
```

the invoice table client_id field has foreign key reference to client table id field

the controller:

```
    public function createAction($id, Request $request) {
        $form = $this->createCreateForm(new Invoice, $id);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager();
            $em->persist($form->getData());
            $em->flush();

            $this->addFlash('success', 'Invoice is created.');

            return $this->redirectToRoute('client_invoice_list', array('id' => $id));
        } else {
            $errors = (string)$form->getErrors(true);
            $form->addError(new FormError($errors));
        }

        return $this->render('WebulousEcocrmBundle:Invoice:create.html.twig', array(
                    '_action' => 'clients',
                    'form' => $form->createView()
        ));
    }

    public function createFormAction($id, Request $request) {
        $client = $this->findClientById($id);

        if (null == $client) {
            return $this->handleNotFound();
        }

        $invoice = new Invoice();
        $form = $this->createCreateForm($invoice, $id);

        return $this->render('WebulousEcocrmBundle:Invoice:create.html.twig', array(
                    '_action' => 'clients',
                    'form' => $form->createView()
        ));
    }

    private function createCreateForm(Invoice $invoice, $id) {
        $form = $this->createForm(new InvoiceType, $invoice, array(
            'method' => 'POST',
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('client_invoice_create_form', array('id' => $id)),
        ));
        // here is the hidden input to store the client_id
        // work fine without relationship, but after added relationship it like ignore this
        $form->add('clientId', 'hidden', array('data' => $id));
        $form->add('stat', 'hidden', array('data' => 0));
        $form->add('submit', 'submit');

        return $form;
    }
```

here is the Invoice Entity

```
<?php

namespace Webulous\EcocrmBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Invoice
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Webulous\EcocrmBundle\Entity\InvoiceRepository")
 */
class Invoice
{
    const STATUS_UNPAID = 0;
    const STATUS_PAID = 1;
    const STATUS_CANCELLED = 2;

    const TAX_CHARGE_PERCENTAGE = 1;
    const TAX_CHARGE_FIXED = 2;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Client", inversedBy="invoice")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="client_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $client;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="client_id", type="integer")
     */
    private $clientId;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="stat", type="smallint")
     */
    private $stat;

    [.......]

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getInvoiceId() {
        return 'MPN#' . str_pad($this->id, 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }

    /**
     * Set clientId
     *
     * @param integer $clientId
     * @return Invoice
     */
    public function setClientId($clientId)
    {
        $this->clientId = $clientId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get clientId
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getClientId()
    {
        return $this->clientId;
    }

    /**
     * Set stat
     *
     * @param integer $stat
     * @return Invoice
     */
    public function setStat($stat)
    {
        $this->stat = $stat;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get stat
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getStat()
    {
        return $this->stat;
    }

    [........]

    public function getStatExplain() {
        return $this->transformStat($this->getStat());
    }

    private function transformStat($value) {
        switch ($value) {
            case self::STATUS_UNPAID:
                return 'Unpaid';
            case self::STATUS_PAID:
                return 'Paid';
            case self::STATUS_CANCELLED:
                return 'Cancelled';
            default:
                return 'Unpaid';
        }
    }

    private function reverseTransformStat($value) {
        switch ($value) {
            case 'Unpaid':
                return self::STATUS_UNPAID;
            case 'Paid':
                return self::STATUS_PAID;
            case 'Cancelled':
                return self::STATUS_CANCELLED;
            default:
                return self::STATUS_UNPAID;
        }
    }

    /** @ORM\PrePersist */
    public function prePresist() {
        $this->created = time();
        $this->updated = time();
    }

    /** @ORM\PreUpdate */
    public function preUpdate() {
        $this->updated = time();
    }

    /**
     * Set client
     *
     * @param \Webulous\EcocrmBundle\Entity\Client $client
     * @return Invoice
     */
    public function setClient(\Webulous\EcocrmBundle\Entity\Client $client = null)
    {
        $this->client = $client;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get client
     *
     * @return \Webulous\EcocrmBundle\Entity\Client 
     */
    public function getClient()
    {
        return $this->client;
    }

    /**
     * Set total
     *
     * @param integer $total
     * @return Invoice
     */
    public function setTotal($total) {
        $this->total = $total;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get stat
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getTotal() {
        //TODO: sum onetomany
        return '1000';
        // return $this->total;
    }
}
```

and here is the client entity

```
<?php

namespace Webulous\EcocrmBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="client")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="username", message="Username is not available.")
 */
class Client
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Invoice", mappedBy="client")
     */
    protected $invoice;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=60, unique=true)
     */
    protected $username;

   [.......]

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Module")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="clients_modules",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="client_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="module_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     **/
    protected $modules;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Transaction")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="clients_transactions",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="client_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="transaction_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     **/
    protected $transactions;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Package", inversedBy="clients")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="package_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $package;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->modules = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->invoice = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     */
    public function prePersist()
    {
        $this->created = time();
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PreUpdate
     */
    public function preUpdate()
    {
        $this->updated = time();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    [......]

    /**
     * Add modules
     *
     * @param \Webulous\EcocrmBundle\Entity\Module $modules
     * @return Client
     */
    public function addModule(\Webulous\EcocrmBundle\Entity\Module $modules)
    {
        $this->modules[] = $modules;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove modules
     *
     * @param \Webulous\EcocrmBundle\Entity\Module $modules
     */
    public function removeModule(\Webulous\EcocrmBundle\Entity\Module $modules)
    {
        $this->modules->removeElement($modules);
    }

    /**
     * Get modules
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getModules()
    {
        return $this->modules;
    }

    /**
     * Add transactions
     *
     * @param \Webulous\EcocrmBundle\Entity\Transaction $transactions
     * @return Client
     */
    public function addTransaction(\Webulous\EcocrmBundle\Entity\Transaction $transactions)
    {
        $this->transactions[] = $transactions;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove transactions
     *
     * @param \Webulous\EcocrmBundle\Entity\Transaction $transactions
     */
    public function removeTransaction(\Webulous\EcocrmBundle\Entity\Transaction $transactions)
    {
        $this->transactions->removeElement($transactions);
    }

    /**
     * Get transactions
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getTransactions()
    {
        return $this->transactions;
    }

    /**
     * Set active
     *
     * @param boolean $active
     * @return Client
     */
    public function setActive($active)
    {
        $this->active = $active;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get active
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function isActive()
    {
        return $this->active;
    }

    public function setAaFormNo($val)
    {
        $this->aaFormNo = $val;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAaFormNo()
    {
        return $this->aaFormNo;
    }

    public function setExpireDate($val)
    {
        $this->expireDate = $val;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getExpireDate()
    {
        return $this->expireDate;
    }

    public function setPackage(Package $package = null)
    {
        $this->package = $package;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPackage()
    {
        return $this->package;
    }

    /**
     * Get active
     *
     * @return boolean 
     */
    public function getActive()
    {
        return $this->active;
    }

    /**
     * Add invoice
     *
     * @param \Webulous\EcocrmBundle\Entity\Invoice $invoice
     * @return Client
     */
    public function addInvoice(\Webulous\EcocrmBundle\Entity\Invoice $invoice)
    {
        $this->invoice[] = $invoice;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove invoice
     *
     * @param \Webulous\EcocrmBundle\Entity\Invoice $invoice
     */
    public function removeInvoice(\Webulous\EcocrmBundle\Entity\Invoice $invoice)
    {
        $this->invoice->removeElement($invoice);
    }

    /**
     * Get invoice
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getInvoice()
    {
        return $this->invoice;
    }
}
```

and here is the form type

```
<?php

namespace Webulous\EcocrmBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class InvoiceType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('fromCompanyName', 'text', array('label' => 'From Company Name', 'data' => 'Default Company Name', 'required' => false))
            ->add('toCompanyName', 'textarea', array('label' => 'To Company Name', 'required' => false))
            ->add('fromCompanyAddress', 'textarea', array(
                'label' => 'From Company Address',
                'data' => 'From Company Address',
                'required' => false
                )
            )
            ->add('toCompanyAddress', 'textarea', array('label' => 'To Company Address', 'required' => false))
            ->add('fromContact', 'text', array('label' => 'From Contact Number', 'data' => '6011111111', 'required' => false))
            ->add('fromEmail', 'email', array('label' => 'From E-Mail', 'data' => 'admin@admin.com', 'required' => false))
            ->add('taxType', 'choice', array('label' => 'Tax Type', 'choices' => array(
                '1' => 'Charge by percentage',
                '2' => 'Charge a fixed cost'
            ), 'required' => false))
            ->add('tax', 'text', array('label' => 'Tax', 'required' => false))
            ->add('taxDescription', 'text', array('label' => 'Tax Description', 'required' => false))
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Webulous\EcocrmBundle\Entity\Invoice'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'webulous_ecocrmbundle_invoice';
    }
}
```

and here is the error message

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO Invoice (client_id, stat, created, updated, from_company_name, to_company_name, from_company_address, to_company_address, from_contact, from_email, tax_type, tax, tax_description) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [null, [.........]]

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'client_id' cannot be null
```

i don't know why is the client_id($clientId) will become null suddenly, i use browser to check the inspect element the hidden input is still there

as i see the invoice entity have

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Client", inversedBy="invoice")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="client_id", referencedColumnName="id")
*/
protected $client;

/**
* @var integer
*
* @ORM\Column(name="client_id", type="integer")
*/
private $clientId;
```

both 2 are aiming the same field client_id, i feel this is the error cause, but i don't know why and don't know how to fix, any idea guys? many appreciate

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution, use the setClient before persist and handleRequest to set the client, then the problem is fix, so i also remove the clientId from Invoice entity, there is no need to duplicate

```
public function createAction($id, Request $request) {
    $client = $this->findClientById($id);

    if (null == $client) {
        return $this->handleNotFound();
    }

    $invoice = new Invoice();
    $invoice->setClient($client);
    $invoice->setStat(0);

    $form = $this->createForm(new InvoiceType, $invoice, array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('client_invoice_create_form', array('id' => $id)),
    ));

    $form->add('submit', 'submit');

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager();
        $em->persist($form->getData());
        $em->flush();

        $this->addFlash('success', 'Invoice is created.');

        return $this->redirectToRoute('client_invoice_list', array('id' => $id));
    } else {
        $errors = (string)$form->getErrors(true);
        $form->addError(new FormError($errors));
    }

    return $this->render('WebulousEcocrmBundle:Invoice:create.html.twig', array(
                '_action' => 'clients',
                'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```

Comment: Rather than set it implicitly you should add a `$invoice->setClient($this)` to your `addInvoice` and a `$invoice->setClient(null)` to you `removeInvoice` in your entity/model. This way you don't need to remember to add these to every create/update.

Comment: public function addInvoice(\Webulous\EcocrmBundle\Entity\Invoice $invoice)
    {
        $this->invoice[] = $invoice;
        $invoice->setClient($this);
        return $this;
    }

like this? this way can use hidden input field ? @Qoop

Comment: It wouldn't allow you to do anything that you didn't do before, it just automatically set or unset the invoice/client relationship without needing to repeatedly use both `$client->addInvoice($invoice)` and `$invoice->setClient($client)` in each update. Also you can shrink down your repository call and the null check into a single line like `if (null === $client = $this->findClientById($id))`.